# merging two datasets into datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I have two datasets which I want to combine into 4 columns.

dsResult - display month, new card qty and new card total.
dsResult2 - display month and top up value.

This is the current code:

```
   DataSet dsResult = objWSX.SelectNewCardSummary(AYear, 
   optCurrency.SelectedValue.ToString());
   DataSet dsResult2 = objWSX.SelectTopupSummary(AYear, 
   optCurrency.SelectedValue.ToString());

   dsResult.Merge(dsResult2);


        if (dsResult != null && dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (DataRow dtRow in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                dgvReport.Rows.Add(
                   dtRow["MonthName"].ToString(),
                   dtRow["new_card_qty"].ToString(),
                   dtRow["new_card_total"].ToString(),
                   dtRow["Top_Up_Value"].ToString()

                );
            }
```

[Current output as displayed here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv542.png)

and I want the output will not have redundancy of months and it fill correctly in datagridview.

Comment: You have two datatables.  Your datasets each have only one table.  So join the two tables by month.  See msdn for examples of join statements : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Can you joing the two using SQL so there is just one DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your `DataTable` to `Enumerable` collection and group by on `Month` column and export new `DataTable` from it,

```
        if (dsResult != null && dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var distinctDataTable = dsResult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("MonthName"))
                .Select(group => new
                {
                    MonthName = group.Key,
                    new_card_qty = group.Sum(e => Convert.ToDouble(e["new_card_qty"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : e["new_card_qty"])),
                    new_card_total = group.Sum(e => Convert.ToDouble(e["new_card_total"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : e["new_card_total"])),
                    Top_Up_Value = group.Sum(e => Convert.ToDouble(e["Top_Up_Value"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : e["Top_Up_Value"])),
                });

            foreach (var dtRow in distinctDataTable)
            {
                dgvReport.Rows.Add(
                   dtRow.MonthName,
                   dtRow.new_card_qty,
                   dtRow.new_card_total,
                   dtRow.Top_Up_Value,
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: it only shows the result from dsResult and not merge with dsResult2 @programtreasures

Comment: @nurwahidah yes because we have selected `First()` in `groupby` result, you need to aggregate your values it it.

Comment: im sorry i didnt understand. can you show me how to do it? @programtreasures

Comment: @nurwahidah sure give me some time

Comment: sure.. please take your time @programtreasures

Comment: got error.. Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. for  Top_Up_Value = group.Sum(e => Convert.ToDouble(e["Top_Up_Value"]))        @programtreasures

Comment: @nurwahidah you need to check `DBNull` value before aggregate check updated answer

Comment: thanks! this is what i wanted. thank you so much for your help @programtreasures